# What is the equivalent to a java static final member variable in C/C++ and how can you initialize it via some computation?

Tags: c++

In java, you can have something like:

```
public class Foo {
  public static final int myStatic = computeValue();

  private int static computeValue() { ... }

}
```

Is there something analogous in C/C++?  (**note - I cannot use c++11 which sadly has all sorts of goodies)**

I would like something like

```
/*static final*/ size_t charsInLong = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%l", MAX_LONG)
```

Comment: So... Where's `final` in your Java code?

Comment: Isn't `snprintf` C++11?

Comment: @NeilKirk hmmm, seems to work on my pre-c++11 g++ compiler/linker on centos 5.6.  maybe gnu had it before it was part of the standard.

Comment: `snprintf` is pretty ancient C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a java expert, but pretty sure

```
class Foo {
public:
    static int myStatic;
private:
    static int computeValue() { return 1; }
};
int Foo::myStatic(computeValue());
```

is equivalent to your Java code (which did not contain the 'final' keyword). To prevent modification of myStatic use const:

```
class Foo {
public:
    const static int myStatic;
private:
    static int computeValue() { return 1; }
};
const int Foo::myStatic(computeValue());
```

Comment: You still have static initialization ordering issues. cf. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogy to java's `final` in C++ is `const` though they're not quite identical.  A const var in C++ cannot be modified after it is initialized.

Comment: They are not identical in general case. But (unless I'm missing something) they are virtually identical when applied to `static` member variables of scalar types specifically.

Comment: const size_t charsInLong = snprintf(...) works great, thanks.  At what point does this initializer get called?

Comment: @marathon: You cannot use a non-constant initializer expression in-class, meaning that your above syntax does not "work great". You have to specify the initializer outside of the class at the point of variable *definition*. And that's what will determine the moment of initialization. It is initialized just like any other static object: at least before some function from the containing translation unit is called or some object from the containing translation unit is used. All static objects defined in a translation unit are initialized in top-to-bottom order.

Comment: @AndreyT yes, I didn't try this in-class.  But it would be easy enough to take the variable and pass it to an initializer in a class to get the same effect.  I just want the value set once and set before the class is published.  This is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static method something like this:

```
class foo {

    public:
    static int bar() 
    {
        static int barval = computation();
        return barval;
    } 

};
```

**N.B. This is NOT thread safe!** Making it so is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: this isn't quite right.  I want something that gets statically initialized.  In my java case, the value gets set when the classloader loads Foo, so there never is a threading issue.

Comment: This is statically initialized. `barval` is initialized the first time `bar()` is called, and then never again. C++ is not Java.

Comment: Isn't that more "lazy initialization" ?  Is there no way to have a member initialized before a class is ever used without calling a method?